# Override back button press from View or external class

Tags: android

What I'm trying to do is intercept the Back button press from an external Class like this:

```
public class AnswerView extends RelativeLayout {

    public AnswerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            Log.i("AlleAntwoorden", "Back button pressed!");
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

I'm adding it like this from my main Activity:

```
RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
mainLayout.addView(new AnswerView(this));
```

Comment: You're off to a good start by providing readable, well formatted code, but what is your actual question?

Comment: @Sam I'm trying to intercept the default behaviour when a user presses the back button on their Android device, but not from the main Activity but from a View within the main Activity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order for a View to receive any event it needs to have focus. I don't see any XML, so let's add a couple characteristics at run time:

```
AnswerView layout = new AnswerView(this);
layout.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
layout.requestFocus();
mainLayout.addView(layout);
```

Now your layout will intercept the back button in your `OnKeyListener`. But if another View has focus, even a child View, the event might be consumed by the child first.
To understand this, add an EditText to your AnswerView:

```
layout.addView(new EditText());
```

If you click the back button while the EditText has focus: the first click closes the soft keyboard, the second click will finish the current Activity like normal. The `OnKeyListener` event is not passed up through the View hierarchy by default.